# Where can I ask a question about a basic cell phone?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a (Verizon) basic (aka "dumb") cell phone, and I have a question about SMS capabilities. Is there a Stack Exchange site for my question?

Comment: Depends what you want to ask. If about security, looks like https://security.stackexchange.com can fit; If about importing from/to android device, https://android.stackexchange.com might fit. If direct question about the phone hardware itself, I'm afraid you're out of luck. (e.g. Super User is clearly not for mobile device questions.)

Comment: To the downvoters: I'd love to hear how the question "does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful."